# Questions on how to structure node js service program

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am rather new to node js and have **some** generalized question with regards to how best to structure the code given the non-blocking nature (async) of many of the built-in modules methods.

I am writing a consuming service where I make a https request to some remote service feed. I receive repeated "chucks" of data (the connection remains open) from the feed server. The chunks received by my .on 'data' handler and are processed and written to a zip archive.

When the feed service has no more data to send my .on 'end' handler is invoked as expected. I also provide a timeout and error handlers.

```
   var fs = require('fs');
   var https = require('https');

   var options = {
      // hostname, port path, etc...
   };

   var req = https.request( options, function(res) {

       res.on('data',function(chunk) {
           // invoke code to process data chunk received...
       });
       res.on('end',function() {
           // logic to close out archive
           // ??? how do I reissue request to capture next volley of data?
       });
   });

   req.end();
   req.setTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT_VALUE, function() {
        req.abort();
        // ???  how do I reissue request
   }
   req.on('error', function(err) {
        // log error;
        // ??? how do I reissue request
   }
   // ???? How to structure code so I don't exit program when server 
   // feed is not active?
```

The above code snippet is pretty much cookie cutter form all the examples shown on-line and the good news is **if** the feed server is active, it works. I can see the .on 'data' handler being invoked numerous times and I also see the .on 'end' handler also invoked when there is no more data to process. FANTASTIC!!!

What I am struggling with are the following scenarios and hence my questions (thanks for being patient with me):

If the remote feed server is not active at the time of executing the server, we never block on any of the calls and we fall through all the code and the program exists. How should I structure this code such that if the server feed is not active that we don't exit the program? We need to have an active read at all times.

Second question (which is related), if we timeout on the request, I will need to from the handler after the aborting the request to reissue the request on the server, likewise from the .on 'end' handler I also need to reissue the request on the feed server for the next volley of data.

What is the best way to structure the code to do this. When reissuing the request do I need to redefine the .on 'data' and .on 'end' handlers?

Any help given would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks in advance Pete

Answer (score 0):

How about repeatedly making requests to the site every 3 second? You can do that via setInterval:

```
let requesting = false

setInterval(() => {
    if (!requesting) {
        requesting = true
        // ... make the request
    }
}, 3000)
```

The `requesting` flag is there to avoid making two requests at the same time. Within the `error`, `end` or `timeout` event, just set `requesting` flag to false.

Comment: I think I need to get a better understanding of what's happening with the request? If no server is active, what happens to the queued request? I need to set up listeners on the request (socket, close and error)...